# facebook login in my app gives nullpointer exception. I do not have the facebook app installed in my phone

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

facebook login in my app gives nullpointer exception. I do not have the facebook app installed in my phone.
The exception is as below.

```
  "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.foodiepipe.foodiepipe/com.example.foodiepipe.foodiepipe.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)\
```

how to check if the facebook app is installed on phone and then allow login?

Answer (score 0):

the error which you are facing maybe due to some other issue.
However, if you want to check if the Facebook application is installed or not then use the method given below:

```
public static boolean isFacebookAppInstalled(Context p_context) throws Throwable
    {
        Intent m_shareIntent;
        PackageManager m_packageManager;
        List<ResolveInfo> m_activityList;
        boolean m_isAppInstall = false;
        try
        {
            m_shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            m_shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            m_packageManager = p_context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            m_activityList = m_packageManager.queryIntentActivities(m_shareIntent, 0);
            for (final ResolveInfo m_app : m_activityList)
            {
                if ((m_app.activityInfo.name).contains("com.facebook.katana"))
                {
                    m_isAppInstall = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable m_e)
        {
            CustomLogHandler.printErrorlog(m_e);
            throw new Throwable(m_e);
        }
        finally
        {
            m_packageManager = null;
            m_activityList = null;
        }
        return m_isAppInstall;
    }
```